# Шорткод карточки товара Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно вывести карточку товара, использую [product_page]. Плохо понимаю, но вроде используется шаблон content-single-product.php, а мне нужно использовать single-product.php
Для этого нужно свой шорткод создать или же можно пойти другим путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. По шаблонам товара woocommerce

По умолчанию проверяется наличие файла single-product.php

Если не найден, то идет работа с woocommerce/content-single-product.php

Можно самостоятельно направить wordpress на свой файл

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-template.php';
 }
 return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

2. По шорткоду

Шорткод - это функция PHP, которую можно задействовать внутри содержимого поста, используя условные обозначения.

Т.е. шорткод нужно вставить в содержимое и он обработается в шаблоне поста согласно правилам типа поста, куда Вы его вставили.

Т.е. если Вы его вставили в "post" -> single.php, "page" -> page.php и т.д.